# ComponentType Error When Clicking Edit Product in Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

When clicking the edit product component type error showing magento 2.3.4

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The "componentType" configuration parameter is required for the "price_per_unit" component.

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The "componentType" configuration parameter is required for the "price_per_unit" component.

```
#1 Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataItem() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:414]
#2 Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataItem() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:321]
#3 Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadata() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:218]
#4 Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:140]
#5 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:103]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php:81]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:350]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:129]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php:55]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:65]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:257]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:882]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php:26]
#14 Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page->setActiveMenu() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Edit.php:82]
#15 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit->execute() called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Interceptor.php:24]
#16 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:108]
#17 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:231]
#18 Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#19 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#20 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:143]
#21 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#22 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#23 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Interceptor.php:39]
#24 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:159]
#25 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:99]
#26 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#27 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#28 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#29 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#30 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#31 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#32 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:40]
```

Answer (score 1):

Though this is long overdue, we deeply apologies for that and hurry to provide you with a solution.

Based on the error provided, the "price_per_unit" attribute is missing in some of your attribute sets. There is a chance that you created/migrated your attribute sets after extension installation.
To solve this problem, please complete the following steps:

1. Open your attribute sets for editing
2. Make sure it contains the following group and the attribute - https://prnt.sc/17n8d4y
   group: mageworx-dynamic-options
   attribute: price_per_unit
3. If no, you need to create this group manually and drag and drop the attribute to this group from the Unassigned Attributes column.

Should you have any further questions or difficulties, we are always happy to assist.
Feel free to contact our Support Team at support@mageworx.com with inquiries.

Kindly,

The Mageworx Team

Answer (score 0):

MageWorx Advanced Product Options - You'd need to speak to MageWorx